# Alternative for AppCompat setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility for AppCompat v23

Tags: android

I just upgraded to `AppCompat v23` and find that `setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility` is deprecated. However I am not able to find out what is the alternative, documentation seems very slim on that.

Please let me know if there is an alternative that can help me show the `ProgressBar` on `SupportActionBar`, and if so how. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Maybe it is slim because *Progress bars are no longer provided in AppCompat*, which is what the API doc says

Comment: You could build in custom progress bar libraries into your Toolbar views. http://stackoverflow.com/a/26546576/2308683

Comment: Yes, I saw that note after posting this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `Toolbar` instead of `SupportActionBar`.

Add the `ProgressBar` into the `Toolbar` like below example.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And then in your `AppCompatActivity`, find `ProgressBar` after retrieving the `Toolbar` and set the `ProgressBar` to visible or invisible when you need it.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    setContentView(R.layout.toolbar);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_spinner);

    //Make progress bar appear when you need it
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // OR Use View.INVISIBLE to  Make progress bar disappear
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, will check !